# Visual studio code how to add a keybinding for a command palette entry

Tags: visual-studio-code, key-bindings

For example, I would like to add a key binding Ctrl+R Ctrl+T for the entry:

Python: Run Python File In Terminal

Many thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do that in the `Preferences` -> `Keyboard Shortcuts` section. Search for "Run Python File in Terminal", select the command and press the little `+` sign on the left.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks.

Comment: This has changed since then. It's now under File -> Preferences -> Keyboard Shortcuts.

Answer (score 3):

You can start the process of creating a keybinding for a command in the command palette while in the command palette as of v1.52 (it is in the Insiders' Build now).  A `Gear` icon has been added on the right of each command that you hover over.  Click it.  (To not use the mouse, arrow down or type to your desired command, hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> <kbd>Tab</kbd> to focus the Gear icon and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>). Demo:

[image: palette keybinding demo]

Comment: What if the command you want to run isn't in the command palette dropdown list? How do you create a custom command and assign it a keybinding? I have tried searching the web including this site and I  can't seem to find an answer that doesn't limit itself to the palette options.

Comment: @FrancisBarton Is the command in the `Keyboard Shortcuts` list?

Comment: no it's not. I've also asked about this in a GitHub issue - aware I am probably limited by my own lack of understanding about VSCode. https://github.com/REditorSupport/vscode-R/issues/1481

Comment: @FrancisBarton I looked through the REditorSupport repo.  It appears they do not `registerCommand` the functionality you want.  They register other things like `vscode.commands.registerCommand('r.showHelp', () =>...` which is what must be done to make a command available for keybinding.  Otherwise it is just not exposed to the user in a way they can separately call it.  You should ask them to register that functionality as a command.

Comment: Thanks so much @Mark that is really helpful. I had no idea.
I do appreciate your comment.