# VS Code Select Previous Occurrence

Tags: visual-studio-code

Visual Studio Code has a handy way to select multiple occurrences of a selection using multiple cursors. If I highlight a word the press Ctrl + D, it'll highlight the next occurrence of the word and put a new cursor at the beginning of the word.

Is there a way I can highlight the **previous** occurrence of a word? I tried Ctrl + U but that just cancels whatever I selected with with Ctrl + D.

Comment: You might want to change your title to mention the previous occurrence rather than the next - it is a little misleading.

Answer (score 5):

You want this command which is unbound by default:

```
{
  "key": "",
  "command": "editor.action.addSelectionToPreviousFindMatch"
}
```

Or search for `Add Selection to Previous Find Match` in the Keyboard Shortcuts (or Command Palette soon, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/64920437/836330).

if by "highlight" the previous result you want to do the same as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> does to the next.

Comment: i wonder if the same can be achieved without pre-highlighting and wuthout using "find text" functionality. Just jumping to prior next occurence. Oh, it seems there actually is: https://stackoverflow.com/q/45901507/976391